# FORTRAN 95 accuracy for division of very large numbers

Tags: fortran

I wrote a subroutine to calculate binomial coefficients (n choose k) that will be used for large values of n and moderate values of k (hence near the maximum for a given n).  The subroutine code is

```
!
!   Subroutine to calculate combinatoric term (n choose x)
!
subroutine COMBO(m,y,combin)
implicit none
integer m,y,b1,b2,maxx,minn
real (kind=16) combin,temp1,temp2
temp1 = real(1,16)
temp2 = real(1,16)
maxx = MAX(y,m-y)
minn = MIN(y,m-y)
do b1 = maxx+1,m
temp1 = temp1*real(b1,16)
enddo
do b2 = 1,minn
temp2 = temp2*real(b2,16)
enddo
combin = temp1/temp2
end subroutine COMBO
```

This works well for moderately large values.  However, if I use n = 100 and k = 55 I get the following

61448471214136179596720592959.998

The decimal part is clearly wrong, since combinations are always whole numbers. The main program is

```
program chkint
implicit none
integer i,j,n,k
real (kind=16) cmb

print*,"what is n?"
read*,n
print*,"what is k?"
read*,k

call combo(n,k,cmb)
print*,cmb

end
```

BTW: kind = 16 is quad precision on my machine.

Thanks

Comment: What compiler are you using? I'm getting `61448471214136179596720592960.0000` which is an expected answer. And decimals are there because `cmb` is real. What you get is an error due to float point calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am using Absoft FORTRAN 95.  If I declare cmb to be integer it doesn't work at all.  Is there anything I can do about the error due to float point calculations?

Comment: I do not have it, used Intel's. It also might depend on the x86 or x64 OS/CPU. If you have x64 compiler and system - why not to use `selected_int_kind(32)`

Comment: If you care about exact numerical accuracy, do **not** use the non-portable `kind=16`, to specify the quadruple precision, but many of the other portable ways. It has been repeated here million times. Even `real*16` is IMO better, but the best is to use a named constant with the working precision, that can be easily changed.

Comment: And in this case try to use the largest integer kind you can get as Cheery suggests.

Comment: I updated the code with                                   integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(31,307) and updated real (kind=16) to real (kind=dp) but I got the same result.  Note that (31,307) was the maximum for the FORTRAN compiler I'm using...I have a 64-bit processor

Comment: Try `integer(ip)`, `ip = selected_int_kind(32)`. It is obvious that would you did now cold not help.

Comment: selected_int_kind(32) returns -1, so my compiler doesn't support this.  Largest is selected_int_kind(18) which returns the value 8.  If I declare an integer, say k, to be of this kind then the function huge(k) returns 9223372036854775807

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the magniitude of integers you're using, there may be portable means of using extended precision integers on your system. The standard module ISO_FORTRAN_ENV should define a number of integer kinds (INT8, INT16, INT32, INT64, etc.) As of Fortran 2008 these are contained in the array INTEGER_KINDS but implementation of this seems spotty at present.

If you're still running out of room, you have two choices: reformulate your problem to work within the precision you have or look for an extended- or arbitrary precision math library. Happily, a number of such libraries are listed at LBNL under http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/

***Update:***

`selected_int_kind` is an alternate dynamic means of creating extended precision values, but you still need to know which 'kind' values are accepted by the compiler. For example:

```
program kind_int
    use iso_fortran_env, only: output_unit, INT8, INT16, INT32, INT64!, &
!        INTEGER_KINDS

    implicit none

    integer :: i

1   format(A)
2   format('Kind name = ', A5, T20, 'kind value = ',I2,                &
        T40, 'maximum = ', I19)
3   format('Available kind values: ', I2, *(', ', I2))
    continue

    write(output_unit, 1) 'Maximum value of supported integer kinds:'
    write(output_unit, 2) 'INT8 ', INT8,  huge(1_INT8)
    write(output_unit, 2) 'INT16', INT16, huge(1_INT16)
    write(output_unit, 2) 'INT32', INT32, huge(1_INT32)
    write(output_unit, 2) 'INT64', INT64, huge(1_INT64)
    write(output_unit, 2) '16   ', 16, huge(selected_int_kind(16))
    write(output_unit, 2) '32   ', 32, huge(selected_int_kind(32))

!    write(output_unit, 3) INTEGER_KINDS

    stop
end program kind_int
```

gives the following with gfortran on a linux64 system:

```
Maximum value of supported integer kinds:
Kind name = INT8   kind value =  1     maximum =                                      127
Kind name = INT16  kind value =  2     maximum =                                    32767
Kind name = INT32  kind value =  4     maximum =                               2147483647
Kind name = INT64  kind value =  8     maximum =                      9223372036854775807
Kind name = ik32   kind value = 16     maximum =  170141183460469231731687303715884105727
Kind name = ikxx   kind value = 16     maximum =  170141183460469231731687303715884105727

Selected int kind value =  1           kind value =    1
Selected int kind value =  2           kind value =    1
Selected int kind value =  3           kind value =    2
Selected int kind value =  4           kind value =    2
Selected int kind value =  5           kind value =    4
Selected int kind value =  6           kind value =    4
Selected int kind value =  7           kind value =    4
Selected int kind value =  8           kind value =    4
Selected int kind value =  9           kind value =    4
Selected int kind value = 10           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 11           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 12           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 13           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 14           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 15           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 16           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 17           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 18           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 19           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 20           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 21           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 22           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 23           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 24           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 25           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 26           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 27           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 28           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 29           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 30           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 31           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 32           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 33           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 34           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 35           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 36           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 37           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 38           kind value =   16
Selected int kind value = 39           kind value =   -1
```

With minor modification, the program yields the following using ifort on the same system:

```
Maximum value of supported integer kinds:
Kind name = INT8   kind value =  1     maximum =                                      127
Kind name = INT16  kind value =  2     maximum =                                    32767
Kind name = INT32  kind value =  4     maximum =                               2147483647
Kind name = INT64  kind value =  8     maximum =                      9223372036854775807

Selected int kind value =  1           kind value =    1
Selected int kind value =  2           kind value =    1
Selected int kind value =  3           kind value =    2
Selected int kind value =  4           kind value =    2
Selected int kind value =  5           kind value =    4
Selected int kind value =  6           kind value =    4
Selected int kind value =  7           kind value =    4
Selected int kind value =  8           kind value =    4
Selected int kind value =  9           kind value =    4
Selected int kind value = 10           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 11           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 12           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 13           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 14           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 15           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 16           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 17           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 18           kind value =    8
Selected int kind value = 19           kind value =   -1
```

As Vladimir F suggests, you can get some extra precision by using `selected_int_type` but it will vary with hardware and compiler and may or may not give you enough precision depending on the problem.

Comment: I would generally agree with you, but one would need `int128` in this case and it is not defined by  ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, even though the 128 bit integer is actually available in some compilers. That's why I prefer `selected_int_kind` already suggested in the comments more than the ISO_FORTRAN_ENV kind constants for this problem.

Comment: One issue with that approach is that you need to know which kind values are allowed as arguments to `selected_int_kind`; I'll clarify this with an updated to my response

Comment: What? You just supply the number of digits you need and is if you get it. Very simple, just count the digits in the question.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. See above.

Comment: Of course! It is not dynamic, it is completely static! The point is you *may* get the usable kind from it, bout you definitely will *not* get it from `iso_fortran_env` named constants (there are other ways). I never said you are guaranteed to get the required kind from `selected_int_kind`, that's why I wrote in the previous comment you need to see if you can get it and why I wrote in the first one it is available in *some* compilers.